# Будет ли код выполнять сильную нагрузку на сервер?

Tags: php

Данный код будет вызывать сильную нагрузку на сервер?

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("./records/*.comm") as $filename) {
        if (!empty($filename)) {
            echo ("<div class=\"dialog-round\">\n<span class=\"d1\"></span><span class=\"d2\"></span><span class=\"d3\"></span>\n<div>");
            $tmpstr=file_get_contents($filename);
            $author=$tmpstr;
            $author=substr_replace($author, '', 0, 10);
            $author=substr_replace($author, '', strpos($author, '|`author`|'));
            $date=$tmpstr;
            $date=substr_replace($date, '', 0, strpos($date, '|~date~|')+8);
            $date=substr_replace($date, '', strpos($date, '|`date`|'));
            $time=$tmpstr;
            $time=substr_replace($time, '', 0, strpos($time, '|~time~|')+8);
            $time=substr_replace($time, '', strpos($time, '|`time`|'));
            $ip=$tmpstr;
            $ip=substr_replace($ip, '', 0, strpos($ip, '|~ip~|')+6);
            $ip=substr_replace($ip, '', strpos($ip, '|`ip`|'));
            $message=$tmpstr;
            $message=substr_replace($message, '', 0, strpos($message, '|~message~|')+11);
            $message=substr_replace($message, '', strpos($message, '|`message`|'));
            $number=$filename;
            $number=substr_replace($number, '', 0, 10);
            $number=substr_replace($number, '', strpos($number, '.'));
            if ($ip==$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
                echo ("<p class=\"line\" style=\"margin: 0;\"><a href=\"?edit=$number\">Редактировать</a> | <a href=\"?delete=$number\">Удалить</a></p>");
            echo ("<p class=\"line\"><b>Автор:</b> $author, $date <b>в</b> $time</p>");
            echo ("<p class=\"line2\"><b>Сообщение:</b>\n<br>\n$message");
            echo ("\n<hr>Имя файла с комментарием: $number");
            echo ("</div>\n<span class=\"d3\"></span><span class=\"d2\"></span><span class=\"d1\"></span>\n</div><br>");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Нагрузка большая, по сравнению с случаем, если-бы вы написали "человеческий" код.

Для сервера-же, нагрузка, вероятнее всего, мала...

Comment: Солидарен, код ужасен, но нагрузка ( во всяком случае я так предполагаю ) - мала

Comment: @timka_s, извините, как умею.

Comment: Просто старайтесь думать когда пишите...

У вас в коде 5 раз берется содержимое одного и того-же файла, зачем?
Занесите текст файла в переменную и работайте с ней...

Comment: @AlexWindHope, уже так и сделал.

Comment: Ну видно что вы *учитесь*, это не претензия а, всего-лишь совет как сделать лучше

Comment: НО! Формат файла и идею использовать кучу файлов - я-бы пересмотрел...

Если вы в ручную не собираетесь редактировать файлы - я-бы использовал serialize()...

Comment: @timka_s, я думал над этим и надумал такое, так как будет легче редактировать, удалять комментарии, для меня, по крайней мере.

Comment: @Никита Рабыкин, конфигурация в текстовом файле - это правильно. 

Не знаю, как в PHP, а во многих скриптовых языках удобно делать конфигурационный файл, который написан на том же языке (обычно он состоит из "операторов присваивания") и исполняемый в текущем контексте устанавливает "глобальные" переменные.

На самом деле этот подход (исполнение неким интерпретатором  конфигурационного файла) применим (с некоторыми усилиями) во многих языках.

Comment: @avp, да, действительно легче. Делал я так всегда, сколько себя помню, практически во всех ЯП, с которыми мне приходилось сталкиваться. Лучше написать что-нибудь большое сразу, а потом всё-время пользоваться коротким и удобным, нежели писать всё время длинным и не ясным. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идея многократно читать один и тот же файл порочна.

Читайте один раз (в $tmpstr), изменения присвойте сразу $author, $date, ... а повторные изменения делайте уже в них.

Comment: @avp, спасибо за совет, сейчас попробую.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код - я-бы переписал так:

```
<?php
  foreach ( glob("./records/*.comm") as $filename ){
    if ( !empty( $filename ) ) {

      preg_match(
        '/^(.*)|~autor~|(.*)|~date~|(.*)|~time~|(.*)|~ip~|(.*)|~message~|(.*)$/',
        file_get_contents( $filename ),
        $res
      );

      list( $number, $autor, $date, $time, $ip, $message ) = $res;

      if ( $ip !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) $edit = '';
      else {
        $edit = ''.
          '<p class = "line" style = "margin: 0;">'.
            '<a href = "?edit='.$number.'">Редактировать</a> | '.
            '<a href = "?delete='.$number.'">Удалить</a>'.
          '</p>';
      }

      echo ''.
        '<div class = "dialog-round">'.
          '<span class = "d1"></span>'.
          '<span class = "d2"></span>'.
          '<span class = "d3"></span>'.
            '<div>'.
              $edit.
              '<p class = "line"><b>Автор:</b> '.$author.' ('.$date.' '.$time.')</p>'.
              '<p class = "line2">'.
                '<b>Сообщение:</b><br>'.$message.'<br>'.
                '<hr>Имя файла с комментарием: '.$number.
              '</p>'.
            '</div>'.
          '<span class = "d3"></span>'.
          '<span class = "d2"></span>'.
          '<span class = "d1"></span>'.
        '</div><br>';
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но я очень мало знаком с регулярными выражениями, а конкретнее, вообще не знаком. Хоть Ваш код намного меньше и более «читателен», я, всё же, воспользуюсь который у меня есть, так как я смогу в любой момент туда добавить что-нибудь и удалить в 2 счёта, а не буду сидеть на разных «Яшах» и «Гошах» в поисках своего ответа на вопрос :)
Но в любом случае, большое спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Никита Рабыкин, а зря, с таким подходом (нежелание разбираться в нормальном коде)вы будете долго находиться в категории новичков.